# How to change the default value of 1000 in "SELECT TOP 1000" in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

The default value in Azure Data Studio for `SELECT TOP 1000` query from the table pop-up menu is 1000. Is there a way to change it?

Searching all over the google shows you how to do that in Visual Studio, but not in Azure Data Studio.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to change it. I went through the code source and I found out that is hardcoded. You can request it as a feature in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio)

Maybe the implementation of code snippet can help, but you will have to set N and TableName every time which is not convenient. You can find more details about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/code-snippets?view=sql-server-2017).

In case you want to do it, you can copy-paste this SQL snippet

```
{
    "Select top N Rows": {
        "prefix": "sqlSelectTopN",
        "body": "SELECT TOP ${1:N} * FROM ${2:TableName}",
        "description": "Select Top N Rows"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Select Top N](https://github.com/jimmystelzer/azuredatastudio-select-top-n) extension for this.